# Difficulty connecting QField to connect to PostGIS

Tags: postgis, qfield

I've been working on setting up a PostGIS server for QField for the past week, today I almost thought I had it working but now QField keeps throwing me one error no matter what I do:

"Connection to database failed could not translate host name 'My server IP address' to address: No address associated with host name"

I have the project working wonderfully in the QGIS environment. I'm not using the built in authentication, I'm using the pg_service.conf approach. I have all my layers set to 'no action'.

At one point I though I had the authentication setup right, then I tried getting Qfield to load a Postgres hosted project and stuff stopped working.

Does anyone have any ideas of a setting I might have screwed up or a step I'm missing?

Comment: listen_addresses='*' https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-connection.html is set?

Comment: This server is hosted through a2 and so I myself have not changed this setting, they did it for me. It works from my pc, could they have excluded IPs of mobile devices? At this point all the devices I am using are connected to the same network and have the same IP address.

Comment: Server-side listens "entry 0.0.0.0 allows listening for all IPv4 addresses"

Comment: Ok, figured out that it was a server side problem, they hadn't fully opened up the listen address

Comment: please answer your own question - you can accept it after a short wait time

Comment: Well actually it's still not working, I thought that was the answer because IT said they fixed it, but the tablet still does not recognize the host name/address. I did find a way to verify that the server is listening, its listen_addresses= *.

Answer (score 3):

How I ended up fixing this was switching how I have my authentication saved. I had been using the pg_service.conf file for authentication, this worked great on my pc but for some reason the same file on my android did not work, it just couldn't read it right. I switched to saving the authentication in the project and shipped that to the tablet, this is technically less secure because anyone who copies the project folder now has that password, but for my purposes this works fine.

Sorry I took forever to get back to this.

Comment: Is it possible for you to go into more detail on how to do this? I'm having the same issue and @mathias isnt clear on how to do this for android.

Comment: Could you explain to me what your issue is? Are you having trouble with making the pg_service.conf file or with using that file for qfield?

Comment: How did you switch saving the authentication to the project? What setting or how do I go about doing that step?

Comment: are you still struggling with this? sorry ive just been off awhile

Answer (score 2):

I found the proper solution for this problem.

"The service file should be saved in Unix format in order to work. One way to do it is to open it with Notepad++ and Edit ► EOL Conversion ► UNIX Format ► File save."
https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/opening_data.html#pg-service-file

That was all it took to get it to work. hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

Since the version 2.0 the `pg_service.conf` file must be placed in : `Android\data\ch.opengis.qfield\files\QField` and no more  directly in a directory named `QField` in the main folder.

Comment: I was using xml auth file in version 1.x of Qfield. After update to 2.x this approach it did not work anymore (I saved it to the correct folder in: Android\data\ch.opengis.qfield\files\QField\auth). I solved my problem by saving connection details for PostGIS directly to project file - basic authentication with store checked. This is not ideal as the password is stored in project file.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I connect QField to PostGIS on Android phone using the connection service file:

First, on Windows PC, create file `.pg_service.conf` to store login information. My file looks like this:

```
[my_service_name]
host=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
port=5432
dbname=my_database_name
user=my_username
password=my_password
sslmode=require
```

Use Notepad++ to convert end-of-line characters to Unix style as described in [Qgis documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/opening_data.html#pg-service-file) and save in `C:\Users\MyUsername\AppData\Roaming\postgresql` - you may have to create the folder `postgresql` yourself.

Second, open Qgis and creat a new project, create a new connection to PostgreSQL using menu `layer > Add layer > Add PostGIS Layer > new`. I filled out the opened form as follow:
[image]

The `name` field could be whatever name you want to call your new connection and the `service` field should be the same as the first line in your `.pg_service.conf` file, minus the brackets - in this case it should be `my_service_name`

At the `Data Source Manager | PostgreSQL` form, choose your newly created connection and click `Connect` - you should be able to connect to your Postgis database and see your layers listed - add any layer you want.

Save your project using `.qgs` format - you are about to achieve your aim of working with Postgis layers on Android phone using QField.

Create a copy of your `.pg_service.conf`, rename it to `pg_service.conf` (remove the first dot in the name) and ship to your Android phone - remember to put it in the folder `Android\data\ch.opengis.qfield\files\QField`.

[image]

Finally, ship the above `.qgs` project to your phone, open it with QField and enjoy!