# QField, QGIS, PostgreSQL working with enterprise database

Tags: qgis, qfield, geospatial-pdf

I am trying to connect many devices together for data capturing using QField 1.9.6 and PostgreSQL. I prepared the data with QGIS 3.20.1, but I keep getting errors when am not using the store options for login. I am doing this because I want each user to login with his own username and password when using QField. I already created in PostgreSQL with roles.

Is there any way to make this happen?
I tried to change hba file to trust all connection
Disable SSL, no action layer in QGIS
Can't find qfield/auth/ directory

Some Reference for other methods

https://www.opengis.ch/2019/10/03/qfield-1-2-released/
https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/auth_system/auth_workflows.html
https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/auth_system/auth_overview.html

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/397964/difficulty-connecting-qfield-to-connect-to-postgis

Comment: thanks Matthias, but still same problem, they used to store login configuration, but I can use that, or I have to prepare the project for each user with his own account

Comment: Have a look at pg_service.conf, that can be prepared on each device and the project itself can be shared

Comment: This one could been used with Qfield, if you have a reference please share it

Comment: https://github.com/opengisch/QField/releases/tag/v1.8.0

Comment: Same error, I just attached a photo to update the question

Comment: The screenshot above shows that the project is configured with a dbname, host, ... i.e. with direct connection and not to use the pg_service.conf file.
When configuring in QGIS, add a new pg connection with a "service" instead of "hostname", "database" etc. Add the layer from this newly created connection.

Comment: thanks for your help, I think this is better still can't find a login dialog, but I can create different config files and distributed per devices, i will answer my question

Answer (score 4):

So I found an Answer as Matthis kuhn suggested to use pg_service.conf.

So I am using widows, and I created a file include each user name and password, then I set it in postgres and I added it to qdield folder in each tablet per user, to use with desktop you need to include the dot IN front of the file name as .pg.service.conf and in qfield remove the dot.